# Writing to global variable/state from apex?

Tags: apex, trigger, global-variables

I'm writing a bunch of Apex triggers that access an external web site. This site issues a token which is valid for a period of time, so I'd like to store it someone globally and reuse it, rather than having to authenticate on every call.

It seems I won't be able to use a static variable in the trigger, as this goes out of scope as soon as the trigger finishes.

I have also found info about reading from global variables, but nothing about creating or writing to them. Is this possible? If not, where can I securely store global (app-level) state?

Comment: you could use *Custom Setting* to store the token and its expiration period.So next time you need it,you can retrieve the value from the *Custom setting* and validate its expiration.if it has expired,you can call the site and update the token and its expiration period and use it.Tutorial on Custom Setting can be found [here](http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2010/01/07/using-list-custom-settings-in-salesforce-com/)

Comment: Praveen, if I were you I'd post your comment as an answer. Maybe describe how to create and access a custom setting and link to the documentation and you've got a perfect answer.

Comment: If above comment helps,i'll post it as the answer so that we can close the question.

Comment: @lex Point noted.Will post it as the answer with proper descriptions.

Comment: @Praveen yes - helpful. can you post as an answer for future reference?

Comment: @stevecook i have updated the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use *Custom Setting* to store the token and its expiration period.
So next time you need it,you can retrieve the value from the Custom setting and validate its expiration.
if it has expired,you can call the site and update the token and its expiration period and use it.

**Setup Custom Setting:** (click [here](https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?id=cs_about.htm&siteLang=en_US) to know more)

1)Go to setup -> Develop -> Custom Settings

2)Click New ->

**Object Name** = *Site_Setting* (for example)

**label** = *Site Setting*

**Setting Type** = *List*

**Visibility** = *Public*(if you are using for managed package,then use *Protected*)

3)After creating the Custom setting,Click Manage to create fields to store *token* and its *expiration period*

**Access the custom setting in Apex:**(click [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_custom_settings.htm) to know more)

Create a custom setting data to store the necessary values:

```
Site_Setting__c setting = new Site_Setting__c(Name = 'Site Token',Token__c='xxxx',Expiration_Period__c='xxxx');
insert setting;
```

**To access it next time:**

```
Site_Setting__c cs = Site_Setting__c.getInstance('Site Token');
// you then have access to cs.Token__c and cs.Expiration_Period__c
```

For more info on usage, you can refer this awesome [Tutorial](http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2010/01/07/using-list-custom-settings-in-salesforce-com/) on custom setting by jeff.